# stopping page refresh at each click

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a page name ask.aspx

I have 4 list views in that page which are binding at the time of page load event.
now when ever i click on the items of list view i get the whole page refreshed.

I have used the update panel but for some reasons it is not working

The code for the same is given below.

aspx page

```
enter code here
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">

   <ContentTemplate>


<fieldset>
<legend><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label></legend>
    <ul class="tags">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server"   CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CategoryId") %>'><%# Eval("Name") %></asp:LinkButton></li>
            </ItemTemplate>    
        </asp:ListView>        
    </ul>
</fieldset>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers></Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

ending the content template and update panel.
similarly for the other three listviews.

at cs page
some calculations are taking place.

Now i dont want the page to refresh every time.
what should be done.
please suggest.

Comment: By refresh, do you mean an actual page refresh where the browser reloads the whole page, or the content of the Update Panel is refreshed?

Comment: the whole page....means the browser also reloads

Answer (score -1):

Remove childrenastrigger property and set updatemode=always